# How to show both at same time Upsell and Related Products In Product View Page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php-7, related-products, up-sells

I want to show Related and Upsell both at the same time in my product view page.

I tried to change **catalog_product_view.xml** many times, but it displays me only upsell products not related.

anyone, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the steps below.

Assume you are using a custom module (if not please create a custom module) named "**Company_MyModule**".

**step 1)** Create a block class **MycrossUpsell.php** under ***/app/code/Company/MyModule/Block***

FIle:**/app/code/Company/MyModule/Block/MycrossUpsell.php**

```
<?php

namespace Company\MyModule\Block;

class MycrossUpsell extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct implements \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
{
     /**
     * @var Collection
     */
    protected $_itemCollection;

    /**
     * Checkout session
     *
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_checkoutSession;

    /**
     * Catalog product visibility
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility
     */
    protected $_catalogProductVisibility;

    /**
     * Checkout cart
     *
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\ResourceModel\Cart
     */
    protected $_checkoutCart;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager
     */
    protected $moduleManager;

     protected $_registry;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\ResourceModel\Cart $checkoutCart
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\ResourceModel\Cart $checkoutCart,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
         \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_checkoutCart = $checkoutCart;
        $this->_catalogProductVisibility = $catalogProductVisibility;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
         $this->_registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $data
        );
    }

        public function getCurrentProduct()
    {        
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    }  


    public function getRelatedProducts(){
         $product = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product');
        /* @var $product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */

        $this->_itemCollection = $product->getRelatedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(
            'required_options'
        )->setPositionOrder()->addStoreFilter();

        if ($this->moduleManager->isEnabled('Magento_Checkout')) {
            $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($this->_itemCollection);
        }
        $this->_itemCollection->setVisibility($this->_catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

        $this->_itemCollection->load();

        foreach ($this->_itemCollection as $product) {
            $product->setDoNotUseCategoryId(true);
        }
        return $this->_itemCollection;

    }


     public function getUpsellProducts(){
         $product = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product');
        /* @var $product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */

        $this->_itemCollection = $product->getUpSellProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(
            'required_options'
        )->setPositionOrder()->addStoreFilter();

        if ($this->moduleManager->isEnabled('Magento_Checkout')) {
            $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($this->_itemCollection);
        }
        $this->_itemCollection->setVisibility($this->_catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

        $this->_itemCollection->load();

        foreach ($this->_itemCollection as $product) {
            $product->setDoNotUseCategoryId(true);
        }
        return $this->_itemCollection;

    }

    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getItems()
    {
        /**
         * getIdentities() depends on _itemCollection populated, but it can be empty if the block is hidden
         * @see https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5897
         */
        if ($this->_itemCollection === null) {
            $this->_prepareData();
        }
        return $this->_itemCollection;
    }

    /**
     * Return identifiers for produced content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getIdentities()
    {
        $identities = [];
        foreach ($this->getItems() as $item) {
            $identities = array_merge($identities, $item->getIdentities());
        }
        return $identities;
    }

    /**
     * Find out if some products can be easy added to cart
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canItemsAddToCart()
    {
        foreach ($this->getItems() as $item) {
            if (!$item->isComposite() && $item->isSaleable() && !$item->getRequiredOptions()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


}
?>
```

**step 2 :** Create phtml file **cross_upsell.phtml** under ***/app/code/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/templates/product/view***

File : **/app/code/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/templates/product/view/cross_upsell.phtml**

```
<?php

            $type = 'related';
            $class = $type;
            $image = 'related_products_list';
            $title = __('Related Products');
            $items = $block->getRelatedProducts(); //$block->getAllItems();
            $limit = $block->getPositionLimit();
            $shuffle = 0;//(int) $block->isShuffled();
            $canItemsAddToCart = $block->canItemsAddToCart();

            $showAddTo = true;
            $showCart = false;
            $templateType = null;
            $description = false;            

?>
<h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>

 <div class="block-title title">
        <strong id="block-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>-heading" role="heading" aria-level="2"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $title ?></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content content" aria-labelledby="block-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>-heading">        
        <div class="products wrapper grid products-grid products-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $type ?>">
            <ol class="products list items product-items">
                <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
                <?php foreach ($items as $_item): ?>
                <?php $available = ''; ?>
                <?php if (!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable() && $type == 'related'): ?>
                    <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                        <?php $available = 'related-available'; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>                
                <div class="product-item-info <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $available ?>">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ '<!-- ' . $image . '-->' ?>
                    <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo">
                        <?= $block->getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml() ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="product details product-item-details">
                        <strong class="product name product-item-name"><a class="product-item-link" title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>">
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a>
                        </strong>

                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>

                            <?php if ($templateType): ?>
                                <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, $templateType) ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php if ($canItemsAddToCart && !$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable() && $type == 'related'): ?>
                                <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                                    <div class="field choice related">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox related" id="related-checkbox<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>" name="related_products[]" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>" />
                                        <label class="label" for="related-checkbox<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span></label>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php if ($showAddTo || $showCart): ?>
                                <div class="product actions product-item-actions">
                                    <?php if ($showCart): ?>
                                        <div class="actions-primary">
                                            <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                                                <?php if ($_item->getTypeInstance()->hasRequiredOptions($_item)): ?>
                                                    <button class="action tocart primary" data-mage-init='{"redirectUrl": {"url": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>"}}' type="button" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                    </button>
                                                <?php else: ?>
                                                    <?php $postDataHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper');
                                                    $postData = $postDataHelper->getPostData($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item), ['product' => $_item->getEntityId()])
                                                    ?>
                                                    <button class="action tocart primary"
                                                            data-post='<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $postData ?>'
                                                            type="button" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                    </button>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            <?php else: ?>
                                                <?php if ($_item->getIsSalable()): ?>
                                                    <div class="stock available"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('In stock') ?></span></div>
                                                <?php else: ?>
                                                    <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>

                                    <?php if ($showAddTo): ?>
                                        <div class="secondary-addto-links actions-secondary" data-role="add-to-links">
                                            <?php if ($addToBlock = $block->getChildBlock('addto')): ?>
                                                <?= $addToBlock->setProduct($_item)->getChildHtml() ?>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?= ($iterator == count($items)+1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
            $type = 'upsell';
            $class = $type;

            $image = 'upsell_products_list';
            $title = __('We found other products you might like!');
            $items = $block->getUpsellProducts();
            $limit = $block->getItemLimit('upsell');
            $shuffle = 0;

            $showAddTo = false;
            $showCart = false;
            $templateType = null;
            $description = false;
            $canItemsAddToCart = false;

?>

<h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
<div class="products wrapper">
            <div class="products list items product-items">
                <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
                <?php foreach ($items as $_item): ?>
                <?php $available = ''; ?>
                <div class="product-item-info>
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ '<!-- ' . $image . '-->' ?>
                    <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo">
                        <?= $block->getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml() ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="product details product-item-details">
                        <strong class="product name product-item-name"><a class="product-item-link" title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>">
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a>
                        </strong>

                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>

                            <?php if ($templateType): ?>
                                <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, $templateType) ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php if ($canItemsAddToCart && !$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable() && $type == 'related'): ?>
                                <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                                    <div class="field choice related">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox related" id="related-checkbox<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>" name="related_products[]" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>" />
                                        <label class="label" for="related-checkbox<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span></label>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php if ($showAddTo || $showCart): ?>
                                <div class="product actions product-item-actions">
                                    <?php if ($showCart): ?>
                                        <div class="actions-primary">
                                            <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                                                <?php if ($_item->getTypeInstance()->hasRequiredOptions($_item)): ?>
                                                    <button class="action tocart primary" data-mage-init='{"redirectUrl": {"url": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>"}}' type="button" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                    </button>
                                                <?php else: ?>
                                                    <?php $postDataHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper');
                                                    $postData = $postDataHelper->getPostData($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item), ['product' => $_item->getEntityId()])
                                                    ?>
                                                    <button class="action tocart primary"
                                                            data-post='<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $postData ?>'
                                                            type="button" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                    </button>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            <?php else: ?>
                                                <?php if ($_item->getIsSalable()): ?>
                                                    <div class="stock available"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('In stock') ?></span></div>
                                                <?php else: ?>
                                                    <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>

                                    <?php if ($showAddTo): ?>
                                        <div class="secondary-addto-links actions-secondary" data-role="add-to-links">
                                            <?php if ($addToBlock = $block->getChildBlock('addto')): ?>
                                                <?= $addToBlock->setProduct($_item)->getChildHtml() ?>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   </div>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Note: Please change PHTML pages code as per your design needs.

**step 3**: Run the following commands from your Magento root and check the product details page

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Pritam it worked

Comment: Welcome @XainIjaz